# In the finder: How many files are you selecting?

Tags: macos, finder

I don't seem to find a way to have Finder tell me how many files are selected? How can I see how many files I have selected in the finder ?

Answer (score 1):

In Finder go to the menu bar (top left). Select View and then Show Status Bar.

Number of files selected is in the status bar (at the bottom).